# Get media collection spatie media library using inertia js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, inertiajs, laravel-medialibrary

I'm using Spatie media library and I can upload images to storage and database. And I'm trying to display a media collection in a Vue component. This is my Controller:

```js
public function showHotelPhoto($id)
{
    $hotel = Hotel::with('media');
    return Inertia::render('AdminHotelPhoto', [
        'data' => $hotel,
    ]);
}
```

And this my Vue component:

```html
<template>
    <breeze-authenticated-layout>
        <template #header>
            <h2 class="font-semibold text-xl text-gray-800 leading-tight">
                Foto Hotel
            </h2>
        </template>


        @foreach ($hotel as $hotels)
            @foreach ($hotels->getMedia('property_images') as $image)
                <div class="-item">
                    <img src="{{ asset($image->getUrl()) }}">
                </div>
            @endforeach
        @endforeach


    </breeze-authenticated-layout>
</template>

<script>
import BreezeAuthenticatedLayout from '@/Layouts/Authenticated'

export default {
    components: {
        BreezeAuthenticatedLayout,
    },
    props: ['data'],
}
</script>
```

I know using `@foreach` can throw an error, but this is only for illustration. I want to loop get media collection in the Vue component.

Comment: pass data to vue instance either by `props` or using an AJAX request to some API endpoint

Answer (score 2):

You should use v-for instead of @foreach.
When you say with media, the media is returned as an array. You can access the path of the image with the original_url parameter in the directory.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).